# External URL re direction issue IN Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a requirement where in I want to redirect to an external Url 
Here is my code 
in routes.rb

> map.connect "/myapp/:someparam" ,
>   :controller => "foocontroller" ,
>   :action => "redirect_to_external_url"

In my foo controller i have this action

> def redirect_to_external_url
>       redirect_to "http://externalurl.com/#{params[:someparam]}.html"
>   end

which will redirect to the external url

The problem That I am facing is
After redirecting, The browser shows "http://externalurl.com/bar.html whereas I want the browser to show "/myapp/bar" url (ex http://mydomain.com/myapp/bar) for seo purpose.

Any idea on how this can be achieved in rails ? 
The Rails version that I am using is 2.3.4

Answer (score 1):

1. Action can only be a method in your controller, not an external url (see Routing guide)
2. When you redirect using redirect_to and use an externel url (as in your example) the router.rb wont even be involved
3. displaying an external page under your own url is not that easy, one way to the that would be using frame forwarding or with a reverse proxy.

Does 'external_url? belong to yourself? or is it from somebody else?

Comment: That external url belongs to us , But external site is implemented on the Java platform running on apache. Wondering if I can do something at the apache level (httpd.conf) to rewrite the external urls and use mydomain.com instead of external domain name

Comment: Okay, not sure how you could fix your problem, I dont have enough context. I suggest you create a new question where you describe the 'general situations/problem' and what you are trying to do, perhaps somebody can give you some general advice.